# get a list in object from firebase in android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get the list of color from firebase and the following code is the method to get the color

Model : Product.java

```
package fyp.hkust.facet.model;

public class Product {

private String name;
private String brand;
private String desc;
private String image;
private String username;
private String uid;

private String color;

public Product()
{

}

public Product(String name,String brand, String desc, String image,String username,String uid,String color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
    this.username = username;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.color = color;
}

public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

}
```

The method that I get from using the above model

```
mDatabase.child(product_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                Log.i("product dataSnapshot.getValue()", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                final Product product_data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                backUp_product_data = product_data;
                if (product_data.getName() != null)
                    product_name_text.setText(product_data.getName());
                if (product_data.getBrand() != null)
                    brand_name_text.setText(product_data.getBrand());
                if (product_data.getDesc() != null)
                    descTextview.setText(product_data.getDesc());
                if( product_data.getUid() != null)
                    product_owner_id = product_data.getUid();

                if(product_data.getColor() != null)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG + " color" , product_data.getColor().toString());

                }
            }
        }
     @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

> E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String

I got the above error. How can I get them as a list? Please give me some helps. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  YOUR_MODEL model = child.getValue(YOUR_MODEL.class);
                                }
```

this if you return Array Of Objects , no one object

and it will be nice if you show your FCM database

..........................................................
**UPDATE**

your problem now is in color cause it`s array

in your model you put  color as String and now Color Is array in databse

so you can edit your model and change Field "Color"  to "colorNO" and make it int as in your database

Comment: So you mean I need to open one more model color,java to get the color?  What is the meaning of show my FCM database? The whole db structure? Thanks